# What is the fastest way to get the lowest eigenvalue and corresponding eigenstate in Mathematica?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalues, sparse-arrays

I tried to use the Arnoldi method to get the smallest eigenvalue and corresponding eigenstate for large matrix. However, Arnoldi did not give me the desired result:

```
d = KroneckerProduct[
      PauliMatrix[3], 
      KroneckerProduct[PauliMatrix[2], PauliMatrix[1]]] - 0.1 KroneckerProduct[PauliMatrix[2], 
      KroneckerProduct[PauliMatrix[1], PauliMatrix[1]]
    ];

Chop[Eigensystem[d]]

Chop[
  -Eigensystem[-d, 1, 
  Method -> {"Arnoldi", "Criteria" -> "RealPart"}]
]
```

The output of the result is

```
{{1.1, 1.1, -1.1, -1.1, 0.9, 
  0.9, -0.9, -0.9}, {{0, 0. + 0.5 I, -0.5, 0, 0, 0. + 0.5 I, 0.5, 
   0}, {0. - 0.5 I, 0, 0, 0.5, 0. - 0.5 I, 0, 0, -0.5}, {0, 
   0. - 0.5 I, -0.5, 0, 0, 0. - 0.5 I, 0.5, 0}, {0. - 0.5 I, 0, 
   0, -0.5, 0. - 0.5 I, 0, 0, 0.5}, {0, 0. + 0.5 I, -0.5, 0, 0, 
   0. - 0.5 I, -0.5, 0}, {0. - 0.5 I, 0, 0, 0.5, 0. + 0.5 I, 0, 0, 
   0.5}, {0, 0. + 0.5 I, 0.5, 0, 0, 0. - 0.5 I, 0.5, 0}, {0. + 0.5 I, 
   0, 0, 0.5, 0. - 0.5 I, 0, 0, 0.5}}}

{{-1.1}, {{-0.0886432 - 0.0997727 I, -0.0529345 + 0.478942 I, 
   0.478942 + 0.0529345 I, -0.0997727 + 0.0886432 I, -0.0886432 - 
    0.0997727 I, -0.0529345 + 0.478942 I, -0.478942 - 0.0529345 I, 
   0.0997727 - 0.0886432 I}}}
```

Even though the eigenvalue seems to be correct, but the eigenvector does not match the result from Eigensystem directly.

Then what is the fastest way to get the smallest eigenvalue and corresponding eigenstate for a large matrix?

Comment: Apparently all eigenvalues of this matrix have multiplicity of 2. Then Arnoldi can return _any_ unit vector from that eigenspace. If you know the multiplicity, it is a good idea to let Arnoldi return the full eigenspace of that eigenvalue with `Eigensystem[-d, 2, Method -> {"Arnoldi", "Criteria" -> "RealPart"}]`.

Comment: In any case, it might be a good idea to return more than one eigenvector like with `Eigensystem[-d, 20, Method -> {"Arnoldi", "Criteria" -> "RealPart"}]`. This is particularly important when many eigenvalues are close to each other (so that an ordering of the approximates need not reflect the true ordering).